# NativeScript - cmd tns run android issue

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Am new to NativeScript.

I have done Full setup ( cmd **tns doctor** with no issues) and created a new project by using cmd **tns create**.

I have installed Android studio as well, also created virtual device by AVD Manager (Pixel 3 API Q).

Now opened the project in Android Studio and run the cmd **tns run android** / **tns run android --bundle** but it throws the error "*Cannot find connected devices. Reconnect any connected devices, verify that your system recognizes them, and run this command again.*"

cmd **tns device** not showing any devices but **tns device android --available-devices** shows devices.

Please help me how to connect device and emulators.

Also, i don't have experience in Android studio.

[image: screenshot of my issue.]

Comment: Did you try launching the emulator manually from Android Studio and then just do `tns run android --bundle`?

Comment: Getting Below issue : Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.
Searching for devices...
Cannot find connected devices.
Emulator start failed with: No emulator image available for device identifier 'undefined'.
To list currently connected devices and verify that the specified identifier exists, run 'tns device'.
To list available emulator images, run 'tns device <Platform> --available-devices'.

Comment: Are the emulators listed when you do `adb devices`?

Comment: Try the ins run command with option --emulator if it works?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new in Nativescript also and take me two days to configure the entire environment to run a Nativescript app with the android emulator without install the Android Studio. So the problema that you have also I had and to fix it just has to add the "ANDROID_AVD_HOME" to your system variables.
[Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0XJH.png)
After that you can run your emulator only in a command line window and in another command line window without close your emulator you can type "tns device" and see the active emulators and then run your application using "tns run" or "tns run android --device emulatorname". That works for my after many attempts

Answer (score 0):

Set Environment path for android emulator. First open environment variables and double click on path in system variables then open new window Edit environment variable and add emulator path in this window. Like show in this images.

[image: 1. Environment Variables]

[image: 2. Edit Environment Variables]